# Python library for html to jpg converting

Tags: python

Is subject exists? The hard way is to convert html to pdf, and then pdf to jpg, but it is unwanted for web-based service.

Comment: The problem is that you would need some HTML rendering engine that renders the HTML first. For example WebKit, or the Gecko rendering engine would work.

Comment: I can install any render I want on my own server, so I need a way to convert generated html into image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the webkit2png python library to achieve this.

https://github.com/AdamN/python-webkit2png/

Comment: Seems like exactly what I need, tnx.

Comment: No worries. I hope it works out for you!